# Python generator chaining refers to last iteration

Tags: python, iterator

In this code:

```
x = [0]

for i in range(10):
    x = (a+i for a in x)

print(list(x)) # [90]
```

I'm chaining generators so that the x in one iteration uses the result of the previous x. But it seems all the x generators use the value of i in the last iteration (9).

How can I make it so that each generators uses the value of i in the iteration that they're created? (So that the final result is 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +...)

Comment: That's it, thanks @IljaEverilä.

Comment: Is this a "why does it behave like that" or "how can I fix this" question? Because in the latter case, I don't really see why you'd want to use generators in the first place, instead of using a list comprehension within the loop, or e.g. reversing the loops to `x = (a+sum(range(10)) for a in x)`.

Comment: It's a simplified example. In my actual code, converting it to a list comprehension/reversing the loop is hard, and I need the behavior of iterators, because the data may not fit in memory.

In any case, the answers on the duplicate solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
x = [0]

for i in range(10):
    x = [a+i for a in x]

print(x)
```

short way:

```
x = [0]
x = sum([i for i in range(10)])
print(x)
```